# warning: statement has no effect (C++)

Tags: c++

Warning: statement has no effect
Line 15
I have to display all the characters from s1 who are found in s2, too.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    char s1[250], s2[250];
    unsigned int i;
    cin.get(s1,250);
    cin.get();
    cin.get(s2,250);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s2);i++)
        tolower(s2[i]);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++)
        if(strchr(s2,tolower(s1[i])))
            cout<<s1[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tolower` returns the lower-case of the argument, doesn't alter the argument itself.

Comment: `tolower(s2[i]);` has indeed no effect. You probably wanted `s2[i] = tolower(s2[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

[std::tolower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) takes it's argument by value and returns the result, and therefore doesn't modify the input value.